# Correct flow to log in user from iOS app to remote API

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, authentication

Here's the logic flow I'm trying to code into my iPhone app:

[image]

I think I understand the technicalities to achieve this (using AFNetworking, connecting to a Rails API using Devise as authentication). The auth_token will be stored in the keychain once the login is successful. What I can't figure out is the best way to go about setting up my app to behave like above.

I want the experience to be good for the user of course, so maybe while it's checking for the token and attempting to login it shows a "loading" screen of some sort.

How would I go about achieving this? I don't know which view controller I should set as the rootviewcontroller in the AppDelegate or how I should set it after the user has logged in. I've tried this in the Facebook app and when I open it I see a blank navigation controller it seems, then my profile view is loaded. What are they doing behind the scenes and is this the best way to go?

I am not using Storyboards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have implemented a similar one, the RootViewController was a "SplashViewController" in a navigationController, showing a nice logo, activity indicator and gives user info about authentication status. It holds the logic for checking stored token there and authentication implementation. If authentication is successfull, ShowUserController is shown by pushing to navigationController stack.

If authentication is failure a LoginViewController is presented modally. SplashViewController implements the delegate of LoginViewController, which does nothing but passing the username and password to SplashViewController. On successfull login, LoginViewController is dismissed and user is directed to ShowUserController.

Comment: I went this route. I created a PathFinderViewController that I set the rootViewController to when the app loads. This checks where to go. If I need to log in I show the login screen modally and attempt the log in. If successful, I dismiss the login screen and change the rootViewController to the UserViewController. If PathFinder finds the Auth_Token is valid it simply changes the rootViewController to the UsersViewController. Thanks!

Comment: @sbonkosky Glad to help you :). BTW how did you create the flow diagram?

Comment: The real question is non of the above for me!
Question is after doing so as stated above, how to handle back whenever the user Logs Out?
What happens to the ViewControllers and RootViewController checking?

Comment: Awesome solution for this programming flow. If you are looking to use a log in view in your iOS app, consider using a `BALogInView`. It is easy to set up and allows for you to get your log in logic done and down to development of the rest of the app. https://github.com/brandonaskea/BALogInView

Answer (score 4):

Start your app with the root controller as the one that the user will see after they have logged in successfully, then layer the login views/controllers on top, with modal calls.  If the authentication is successful, your user will already be where they want to be, else you call the login layers modally on top.  Once they're authenticated, you won't need the login views anymore.

Comment: But what do I do if the user has a slow data connection and the check to see if the auth_token is valid takes a few seconds? what do I show in the meantime?

Comment: You can put up any modal view you like.  Put up a modal view with a spinner and some text that dismisses when the token validation is complete.  For example, put up the root controller, than a modal "loading..." view with spinner until the authentication is complete.  If it's bad, dismiss the spinner view, and put up the login view. If it's good, just dismiss the spinner view.  Having it all controlled from your root view controller makes your life simpler.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on @Owen Hartnett's answer since this text won't fit in a comment; This is how I've seen Facebook's SDK work. If you build an app that uses the Facebook iOS SDK as the only login mechanism, then the way it works is like this:

In my app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method I first check for an "already on file" access token in say, `NSUserDefaults`. If not found, I need to get one and so have my app delegate immediately launch a modal login flow that finishes with a valid access token that is then saved to `NSUserDefaults` for use on next app open.

If I do already have an access token on file in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, then I assume the happy path and open a "logged in user session" asynchronously using the access token I found on file at time of app open. If the access token I have on file to open the session with is legit, then no UX is displayed. If the access token I have on file is an illegitimate access token (server says it's too old, for example), then my open session method in my app delegate, upon finding this out, will display the proper modal login flow.

Since this openSession method executes asynchronously, you might be wondering how your root view controller, which needs a logged in user, is going to function in the meantime.

The answer is that it should be written as if it does have a logged in user. It should assume. If it ever runs code that can't run or finish executing successfully because it doesn't have a valid access token then that code should trigger the login UI *if it's not already presented* (i.e. the access token check on app open, by this time, has already presented the modal login UI to the user).

Lastly, this is a translated version of the Facebook SDK login flow. For example, if you use only their SDK you wouldn't ever be interfacing with `NSUserDefaults` like I suggest. I've translated their flow to a "custom implementation" of logging in to a remote API.